# Initialize a Scrabble board's special tiles algorithmically?

Tags: design-patterns, math

Is there an algorithm to initialize the tiles on a scrabble board rather than manually laying them out like so:

```
board[0][3]->setType(ScrabbleTile::TripleWord);
board[0][6]->setType(ScrabbleTile::TripleLetter);
board[0][8]->setType(ScrabbleTile::TripleLetter);
board[0][11]->setType(ScrabbleTile::TripleWord);
...
```

It looks like there may be a pattern by looking at the board but it's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Potentially, but given the limited size of a scrabble board -- is it really worth it?

Comment: Aren't there larger board sizes for certain Scrabble-type games?

Comment: For everyone who hasn't memorized the special tiles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_Scrabble_board_with_coordinates.svg

Comment: @chris C'mon now, let a man shave his yak!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Scrabble board is symmetric about both the horizontal and vertical centre lines. Therefore you could get some efficiency by setting up a quarter of the board, then flipping that to end up with half a board, then flipping that again to get the whole board.

**Edit:** It's also symmetric about the diagonals, so you should be able to seed the board from a small triangle and replicate it from there.